# Series about four high school students getting trapped in another dimension

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe

I'm searching for a series that I want to watch again, but can't find.

It's about four high school students who get sucked into a tornado (that someone in their group accidentally summoned with magic), and end up in an alternate universe where they were never born and all have elemental powers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you referring to a _TV_ series? If so, in roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch it, and was it live-action or animated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Nowhere Boys](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2761354/)*** (2013–2018).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys):

> *Nowhere Boys* is an Australian teen drama television series created by Tony Ayres. It was first broadcast on ABC3 (which is now officially named ABCME) on 7 November 2013. The first two series follow the adventures of four mismatched teenage boys – goth Felix Ferne (Dougie Baldwin), nerd Andrew "Andy" Lau (Joel Lok), golden child Sam Conte (Rahart Adams), and alpha jock Jake Riles (Matt Testro). Nowhere Boys was renewed for a second series which began airing from 23 November 2014. An 80-minute feature-length movie based on the show, titled *[Nowhere Boys: The Book of Shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys:_The_Book_of_Shadows)*, premiered in selected Australian movie theatres on 1 January 2016.

> **After returning home from a school excursion, four boys, Felix Ferne, Andy Lau, Sam Conte, and Jake Riles find themselves in an alternate reality where no one recognises them.** They battle mystical threats and demons to find their way back home.
>
> **One week after the boys return home, they discover they have special elemental powers** after returning from the alternate reality but when they thought they were at peace, they discover they weren't the only ones who crossed over from the alternate reality.

You can see the boys being chased by a tornado at around the [0:39](https://youtu.be/YxPc2eJE_4k?t=39) mark in the video below.

Comment: Yes thats the one i meant thank you

Comment: Looks like we had this one before, but I think this is the better example, so I ran the dupe the other direction.

Comment: That summary quote is confusing. It IDs 4 boys (Felix, Andy, Sam, Jake), then later talks about Luke who encounters 4 boys (Ben, Heath, Nicco, Jesse). Are these other 4 names their alternate reality names or are they 4 other boys? (I realize you're quoting something someone else wrote, so not a ding on you by any means.)

Comment: @FreeMan - Going by the Wikipedia page, the first two paragraphs are about the main cast of the first two seasons of the show, and the third paragraph is about the new cast who replaced them from season 3 onwards.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did peruse the Wiki page, but didn't pick up on that.